# Moving Window MATLAB from Array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hello working on this problem and I can't find a solid way to solve. Easier to show some inputs and outputs.

```
k=3
I = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
myWindow(I, k)
O(1) = [1 2 3]
O(2) = [1 2 3 4]
0(4) = [2 3 4 5 6]
... O(7) = [5 6 7].
```

As you can see the size of the window is '3' such that I keep two neighboring points, at the edges I can keep 1, 2 or no points. Any help is appreciated in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous function approach could be:

```
myWindow = @(n) I(max(1, n-k+1):min(numel(I), n+k-1));
```

Please note that if `I` or `k` are modified at a later time, `myWindow()` will not be automatically updated unless the above command is run again.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.